# Linq query not returning records

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
public tblCustomerDetail GetCustomerDetailsByID(long ID)
        {
            var customer = from c in DataContext.GetTable<tblCustomerDetail>() where c.ID == ID select c;
            return customer as tblCustomerDetail;
        }
```

DataContext.GetTable() has records in it and after filtering based on ID, there are no records in customer variable, although the record with the ID for which I am searching exists in the returned table.

Please help. I am new to LINQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable customer will be of type `IEnumerable<tblCustomerDetail>` so when you cast it with the `as` operator, the result will be null because the types are incompatible.

Try this instead:

```
public tblCustomerDetail GetCustomerDetailsByID(long ID)
{
    var customer = from c in DataContext.GetTable<tblCustomerDetail>() where c.ID == ID select c;
    return customer.First();
}
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons I like to avoid the as operator in general. Casting exceptions are more immediate and informative than null reference exceptions.